# How to choose a boundary layer coordinate or stretching transformation in matched asymptotic expansion

Tags: perturbation-theory

In matched asymptotic expansions how should one properly chose a boundary layer coordinate or stretching transformation. At the moment I am following example 2.3 from *Introduction to Perturbation Methods* by Holmes which uses matched asymptotic expansion to solve
\begin{align}
\varepsilon^2 y'' + \varepsilon xy' - y = -\mathrm{e}^x
\end{align}
with the boundary conditions 
\begin{align}
y(0) = 2, \quad \textrm{and} \quad y(1) = 1.
\end{align}
This problem has two boundary layers at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$ and therefore the book chooses two boundary layer coordinates, that is 
\begin{align}
\bar{x} = \dfrac{x}{\varepsilon^\alpha}, \quad \textrm{and} \quad \tilde{x} = \dfrac{x-1}{\varepsilon^\beta}.
\end{align}

Why should one choose these coordinates? For the boundary layer at $x = 1$, why not choose a coordinate like
\begin{align}
\tilde{x} = \dfrac{1-x}{\varepsilon^\beta} \hspace{3cm} (1)\\ \textrm{or}  \hspace{3cm}\\
\tilde{x} = \dfrac{\sqrt{1^2-x^2}}{\varepsilon^\beta} \hspace{3cm} (2)
\end{align}

If I used the boundary layer coordinate in (1), then I could match the solution in the limit of $\tilde{y}(\tilde{x} \to \infty) = y(x \to 1)$ instead of $\tilde{y}(\tilde{x} \to -\infty) = y(x \to 1)$. Aside from the sign, I don't think this is any different from the original coordinate.

If I used the boundary layer coordinate in (2), then it seems like the matching would still take place at $\tilde{y}(\tilde{x} \to \infty) = y(x \to 1)$ except that the amount of stretching would be different. Are there guidelines for how I should choose my boundary layer coordinate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no substantive difference between the boundary layer variable
$$\tilde{x}=\frac{x-1}{\varepsilon^{\beta}}$$ and the one you give as equation (1).  They only differ by a minus sign, which you correctly observe makes no difference.  In fact, I would choose the version indicated by (1) myself, so that positive values of $\tilde{x}$ fall within the $0<x<1$ domain.

The situation with eq. (2) is a little more complicated.  You can use a boundary later coordinate like that, but it makes things somewhat more complicated.  First notice that, within the boundary layer near $x=1$ you can make the approximation
$$\sqrt{1-x^{2}}=\sqrt{(1+x)(1-x)}\approx\sqrt{2(1-x)}.$$
This can be used to solve for the boundary layer structure, with (as you noticed) a different stretch factor; it essentially amounts to using the square root of your coordinate from eq. (1).  The root just makes things more complicated to work with in practice.

Comment: So it seems like there is some freedom in picking the coordinate and that any of the above coordinates could potentially work. However I should obviously pick one that makes my life easy. I also realized that for coordinate (1), $ dx = -\varepsilon d\tilde{x}$ is much simpler than $dx = -(\varepsilon^{2\beta}\tilde{x}/x)d\tilde{x}$ for coordinate (2). Substituting (2) into the governing equation would make things much more complicated it seems.

Comment: I asked a related question about picking the power in the boundary layer coordinate. If you know the answer I would really appreciate the help. Thanks https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/468163/how-to-pick-a-boundary-layer-coordinate-or-stretching-transformation