# How to pick a boundary layer coordinate or stretching transformation

Tags: coordinate-systems, differentiation, perturbation-theory

I am following *Introduction to Perturbation Methods* by Holmes and am unsure how I to pick the power in my boundary layer coordinate if my governing equation is the Laplace equation given by
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 f(r,\theta) = f_{rr} + \dfrac{1}{r}f_r+\dfrac{1}{r^2}f_{\theta\theta} = 0
\end{equation}

If I expand my function as $f = f_0 + \epsilon f_1 + ...$ and use the boundary layer coordinate given by 
\begin{equation}
\bar{r} = \dfrac{r}{\epsilon^\alpha}\\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial r} = \dfrac{1}{\epsilon^\alpha}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \bar{r}}
\end{equation}
then I obtain
\begin{equation}
\nabla^2 f(\bar{r},\theta) = \left[\dfrac{1}{\epsilon^{2\alpha}}(f_{0,\bar{r}\bar{r}}+ \epsilon f_{1,\bar{r}\bar{r}} + ...)\right] + \left[\dfrac{1}{\bar{r}\epsilon^{2\alpha}}(f_{0,\bar{r}}+ \epsilon f_{1,\bar{r}} + ...)\right]+\left[\dfrac{1}{\bar{r}^2\epsilon^{2\alpha}}(f_{0,\theta\theta}+ \epsilon f_{0,\theta\theta}+...)\right] = 0
\end{equation}

From what I understand I want pick $\alpha$ so that each of the terms in the square brackets are the same order of magnitude. However in this case it doesn't seem to matter what $\alpha$ is. Could I just pick $\alpha = 0$ to make my life easy?

Comment: Well I imagine you actually want *non-trivial* solutions, so $\alpha=0$ would be out.

Comment: @KyleKanos why does $\alpha = 0$ give trivial solutions? Setting $\alpha = 0$ and collecting the terms of order one gives me the equation $f_{0,\bar{r}\bar{r}} + f_{0,\bar{r}} + f_{0,\theta\theta} = 0$ which appears to be the Laplace equation for $f_0$ which has many non-trivial solutions.